# Input line that stays at the bottom of the screen

Tags: ruby, linux, console

My program constantly outputs text to the terminal. I need the user input line to always stay below this output; if the user types something, it shouldn't jump over the output.

Is there any Ruby library that can provide this functionality?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean..

Comment: How are you printing your text to the terminal?

Comment: Sorry, yes I'm using puts.

Comment: Can you recreate an example of your issue in the question?

Comment: There is a [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) library for Ruby. See http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html. I've not used the Ruby library, but in the past I've used curses to create a split screen.

Comment: @JimMischel, if you use put your question as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @mfisher91: Answers that consist of only a link are discouraged, because the link might go stale. I don't have anything else to add to the answer, so I'll just leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There could not be any ruby library providing this functionality since none of the known terminals support splitting the areas inside themselves.

This is the terminal issue: they are not capable of dividing their internal window into two parts.

What you can do, though, it to use *two different shells* for input and for output with [`IO#popen`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-popen).